# What materials are resistant to hot chlorine?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, alloy, corrosion

I'm looking to do an experiment involving hot chlorine gas (900 Celsius), however at the moment the only material I'm aware of that could cope with this is Hastelloy's C-22 alloy. What other alternatives exist?

Comment: How much water is this chlorine going to have with it? Wet chlorine and dry chlorine behave differently.

Comment: The system will be entirely flooded with nitrogen so there shouldn't be any HCl

Comment: I'm not sure simply flooding the piping volume with N2 will prevent HCl formation if there's significant amounts of water in the Cl supply or in the piping but make sure to discuss the wet case with the materials specialists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer — none. Hastelloy C276 or C22 are the best alloys, also considering availability, presumably cost is no object. At that high temperature there is no readily available data. At 500 °C for a limited time experiment, other nickel alloys like 625 or 201 and even 316 SS have some limited life. But for 900 °C, I expect the Hastelloy C family was recommended because they have the best life at about 500 °C. Your conditions are where it would be best to get a manufacturer of high alloys or ceramics to work with you.

Comment: You are dealing with nasty stuff. For example , i saw liquid bromine ( less active than chlorine ) spontaneously  ignite a piece of titanium at room temperature. The titanium had been in a Hastelloy C holder which partly melted during the incident.

Comment: Alloy 22 has been specifically tested with chlorine which is why I was using it as my example.